# table for multi device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a long table, 10*10 cells.  It looks good in desktop but I want to display the same table code to be used for mobile and ipad. Is there a trick to use single code for table for desktop and mobile?

The major issue I am facing is that the table needs to be accessible, and should work with non js version.

I tried to search but many have posted that they use different table for different devices, which I don't want to do.

Comment: sounds like you're looking for a responsive data table: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-table-roundup/

Comment: you should put this comment as an answer so i can upvote it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it would be difficult to do it with plain HTML/CSS. By introducing a scripting language, it should be easier to implement. [Look at the following link for more info](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/detect_apple_iphone_user_web_site_server.html)

A request to the server contains all type of info in it, where it is coming from, which browser they are using and which type of device it is. You should be able to utilize it. Again you have to use script. You can also use JavaSacript but since that is not your option, Script will the only way to do it. Such as PHP, ASP.NET or any other that you are using.